# How can I use Google Spreadsheet API from Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, go

I need to be able to read and write data to a spreadsheet. I am programming in the Go Language in Google App Engine.

Comment: Is this you, Phil?  http://code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/issues/detail?id=12  That's the Go library I would have expected to see Spreadsheet support, but of course it's missing.

Comment: Yes Dusty, its me. I need it for a project that I wrote for the Google App Developer challenge, but I had to submit my app about a week ago. So I didn't get the spreadsheet into it.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting an old thread, but did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of time has passed since this question was asked and answered. Interaction with Google Sheets from golang is much better now.

Currently the "Google Apps Script Execution API" offers the broadest access. Get started here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/go

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is not a supported GData client library for Go. There is a project called [gdata-go-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-go-client/) on Google Code, but its [support for Docs is unimplemented](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-go-client/source/browse/gdata/docs/doc.go). That functionality would need to be ported from another existing client library, e.g. from [Java](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/checkout) or [.NET](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/checkout).

Comment: But I could use REST API it seems, thats a bit low level.