# Go reading Google spreadsheet

Tags: go, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am making an automated bot, and one feature that I would like to include would be the ability to read from a Google spreadsheet.

I have set up a [test spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rSqgPfuZZfPMDEjziMOsJIJjCaN0DEGcX4ifUZ0vBrQ/edit?usp=sharing)  Is it possible to make Go code that can read the values of a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, and c2. If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't yet a library to access Google Docs / Drive for Go.

More information can be found here: [How can I use Google Spreadsheet API from Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788562/how-can-i-use-google-spreadsheet-api-from-google-go-language-golang)